# Drupal: $_POST and MENU_CALLBACK. How works?

Tags: post, drupal-7, hook-menu

i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131209/how-to-pass-arrays-to-drupal-menu-callbacks) ad [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36261/how-can-i-get-post-data-in-a-callback) but nothing is working for me
I'd like to create a menu like this

```js
$items['login'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_login',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => true,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

in order to send a POST to http://www.example.com/login. The body contains a json with username e password. Everything is ok, except for $_POST under function mymodule_login that does not works. $_POST is empty. What's wrong? Is there another "drupalic" way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Or make sure your form url using trailing slash:

```
<form action="login/" method="post">
```